# Laravel 5.4 MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Having trouble with a route with two variables.
I've got a form to delete an item.

```
<form action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}/">
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Upon clicking Delete, I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Here's my routes file.

```
//authenticated users only
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
{
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () 
    {
        /*Some other routes*/

        //Matches "/admin/room/{room}/image[s]?"
        Route::get('room/{room}/image', 'RoomImagesController@index')
        ->name('admin.roomimages');
        Route::get('room/{room}/image/create','RoomImagesController@create');
        Route::post('room/{room}/image','RoomImagesController@store');
        Route::delete('room/{room}/image/{image}','RoomImagesContoller@destroy');

        //Matches the "/admin/room[s]?" URL
        Route::get('/rooms', 'AdminController@rooms');      
        Route::get('/room/create', 'RoomController@create');
        Route::get('/room/{room}', 'RoomController@edit');  
        Route::post('/room/search','RoomController@search');
        Route::post('/room/store', 'RoomController@store'); 
        Route::post('/room/{room}','RoomController@update');    
        Route::delete('/room/{room}','RoomController@destroy');
        
        /*some more routes.*/
    }
}
```

And my RoomImagesController class

```
class RoomImagesController extends Controller
{
    /*Other Methods*/
    public function destroy(Room $room, RoomImage $image)
    {
        dd($room, $image);
    }
}
```

The URL I'm sent to is:

`http://domain.name/admin/room/1/image/1?_method=DELETE&_token=/*tokenValue*/`

Not sure why I'm having issues here! If anyone could shed some light I'd appreciate it. Let me know if you need any more information.

---

### Edit

I've added method="post" to the form, with the same error. Here's a raw paste from the webpage.

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/room/1/image/4/">
    <input name="_method" value="DELETE" type="hidden">
    <input name="_token" value="lFrYPuzz8pY4EEJZEKCtZgjGM4dkk6uTD3p0jhpK" type="hidden">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" type="submit">
</form>
```

---

### Edit 2

Named routes seemed like a solution!

```
//web.php
Route::post('room/{room}/image/{image}','RoomImagesContoller@delete')
    ->name('admin.deleteRoomImages');

//x.blade.php
<form action="{{ route('admin.deleteRoomImages', [ 
                        'room'  => $room->id, 
                        'image' => $img->id ]) }}/"
      method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

But I still get the MethodNotAllowedError

It may be worth noting when I ran `php artisan route:list` I've found that i get a ReflectionError 'RoomImagesController does not exist'
I'll investigate this further!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `http://domain.name/admin/room/1/image/1?_method=DELETE&_token=/*tokenValue*/` url?

Comment: Here's a paste (exclusing domain) `/admin/room/1/image/4?_method=DELETE&_token=lFrYPuzz8pY4EEJZEKCtZgjGM4dkk6uTD3p0jhpK`

Comment: try to change `{{method_field('DELETE')}}` to  `{{ method_field('delete') }}`

Comment: Ashish, I've done so `<input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden">`, no changes.

Comment: I've moved `Route::delete('/room/{room}',...);` above `Route::delete('/room/{room}/image/{image}',...);` still no improvements.

Comment: then remove all those extra things. and just give `form method="delete"`

Comment: Ashish, I thought because DELETE, PUT, PATCH were HTTP only verbs, and HTML only supports GET and POST in forms, we needed to add it as hidden field _method in our forms. I will try though.
**Edit** Same error Ashish :(

Comment: Try to run `composer dump-autoload` to autoload the files and try again to resolve the controller not found issue

Comment: try `action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}"` remove last `slash`

Comment: Remove the trailing slash @AjayDeepakKumar answer should be the solution I guess

Comment: I agree with @AjayDeepakKumar this is the correct solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is happening because you are making a request to wrong url

it must be `action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}"` not `action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}/"`

why it is happening you made a request to `action="/admin/room/1/image/4/"` which is being showing moved to `action="/admin/room/1/image/4"` and you lose method field which is `DELETE`  that's why you are getting error try to use below example and it will work fine.

```
<form action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}" method="post">
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: I think this may be correct afterall because of the trailing slash

Comment: Ajay, thanks. This was the reason. I thought I had done this, I had followed [linktoahref's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808894/linktoahref) answer, which contained the trailing /. I'd better take attention to detail off my resume.

Answer (score 5):

Add `method="post"` as an attribute to your form. Like so:

```
<form action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}" method="post">
```

If the `method` attribute is not provided, the form is submitted via `GET` by default. `DELETE` method requires the data to be submitted via `POST`.

Comment: @UnnecessaryMoney try to clear your cached route with `php artisan route:clear` you might want to clear the cached view too with `php artisan view:clear` if this does not work then you can create a simple route and just return a string to do a step by step debug. I think you should have no problem having added the right method.

Answer (score 1):

Set a method attribute on the form to POST
So you have

```
<form action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}/" method="POST">
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: how can it work if request been redirected to  moved page

Comment: Really don't understand. can you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

```
Route::delete('room/{room}/image/{image}',
              'RoomImagesContoller@destroy')->name('deleteRoomImages');
```

and use the [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) helper method in your form

```
<form action="{{ route('deleteRoomImages', [ 
                'room'  => $room->id, 
                'image' => $img->id ]) }}/" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `POST` method by passing `method="POST"` and add delete method hidden field inside the form tag

```
<form action="/admin/room/{{$room->id}}/image/{{$img->id}}/" method="post">
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Run `composer dump-autoload` to clear the ReflectionException. 
If you copied the class file and modified it, verify that the name of the class is `RoomImagesController` and run `composer dump-autoload`. 
Good luck!

Comment: Just to leave a note, I think just down voting without a comment should be revised. Also @KunsalAjay you can make a modification to your answer to reflect one of the issue the OP encountered (that is, the reason you have this kind of answer) and maybe next time include a little description to why you gave the answer so that it may look complete and avoid being down voted.